# Apache bench and python BaseHTTPServer broken pipe exception

Tags: python, apache, benchmarking, basehttpserver

I have a simple HTTP server implemented in python as follows:

```
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

class Handler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write('Hello World!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        server = HTTPServer(('', 8000), Handler)
        print 'Listening on 0.0.0.0:8000'
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print '^C, halting'
        server.socket.close()
```

Then I run apache bench with concurrency level of 50:

```
ab -v 3 -c 50 -n 50000 http://localhost:8000/
```

I started getting this error in apache bench:

> apr_socket_recv: Connection reset by peer (104)

and on the HTTP server console I see this:

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 51545)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 281, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 307, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 320, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 615, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 329, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 323, in handle_one_request
    method()
  File "./test.py", line 12, in do_GET
    self.send_response(200)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 384, in send_response
    self.send_header('Server', self.version_string())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 390, in send_header
    self.wfile.write("%s: %s\r\n" % (keyword, value))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 300, in write
    self.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 286, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(buffer)
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Also I notice that the HTTPServer gets real sluggish

I have tried to increase the `request_queue_size` of HTTPServer by doing this:

```
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
class MyServer(HTTPServer):
    request_queue_size = 100
    timeout = None


class Handler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    counter = 0

    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(str(self.counter))
        Handler.counter += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        server = MyServer(('', 8000), Handler)
        print 'Listening on 0.0.0.0:8000'
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print '^C, halting'
        server.socket.close()
```

but I still get the broken pipe error at the end of the test run once in a while. If I increase `request_queue_size` to a huge number then the error goes away. I don't understand why because the Apache bench `-c` value is 50 and `request_queue_size` of 100 should be sufficient. Why is it that the `request_queue_size` needs to be much bigger than the Apache bench concurrency setting? Does Apache bench fire off more connections even if the previous one hasn't finished and hence the total number of concurrent connections can be more than the `-c` setting?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with apachebench, but not with httperf. I'm not really sure what the difference in they way they handle the connection is.

Increase from default(5) to 1000. I haven't noticed any huge blowups in memory and performance has increased dramatically, while eliminating errors.

Comment: Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](//stackoverflow.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Stack Overflow way of saying thank you.

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth if you look closer, there are no other answers, and this one is not just saying thanks, there is also a possible solution in it

Comment: My interpretation of Beomagi's answer is that increasing request_queue_size fixed the problem for them as it did for OP. Possibly "use httperf" is an answer. Beomagi, can you clarify?

Comment: It did help, but I may have spoken too soon, still failing with larger number of requests, and larger returned page sizes.
httpperf benchmarking doesn't have this problem, i'm only seeing it with apache bench. will have to tcpdump and figure out why.